# Why my function doesn't see state value in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have component which provide double bind for input. So I want convey data to parent component with 2 ways: onBlur and on Enter button. Function which listens blur event works properly, but another function which have the same functionality do not see state data. I can't fix this bug for 2 hours!!

```
function NewFriend({ cancel = f => f, addNewFriend = f => f }) {
    const [inputProps, resetValue] = useInput('');

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log(inputProps.value) // works correctly
    }, [inputProps.value])

    const blur = () => {
        // it's works correctly
        addNewFriend(inputProps.value)
        resetValue('')
    }
    const keyDownHandlers = event => {
        console.log(inputProps.value) // printing empty string
        if (event.code === 'Enter') {
            addNewFriend(inputProps.value)
            resetValue('')
        };
        if (event.code === 'Escape') cancel();
    }
    useEffect(() => {
        document.addEventListener('keydown', keyDownHandlers)
        return () =>
            document.removeEventListener('keydown', keyDownHandlers)
    }, [])
    return (
        <div className='add-people'>
            <input
                type='text'
                className='new-friend-input'
                onBlur={blur}
                autoFocus
                {...inputProps} />
        </div>
    )
}
```

useInput hook:

```
export const useInput = initialValue => {
const [value, setValue] = useState(initialValue)
return [
    {
        value: value, onChange: event => setValue(event.target.value)
    },
    () => setValue(initialValue)
]}
```

Comment: can you move this to codesandbox?

Comment: `keyDownHandlers` is a closure over the initial `inputProps`. It does not reflect the current state. Given the current code, keyDownHandlers should be indside the `useEffect()` where it's used.